# What is a word that describes an opinion that nominally supports one opinion but in practice hurts or discredit it?

Tags: single-word-requests

Other than the word that describes the opinion, is there also an adjective that is used to describe someone who thinks or pretends that they are on your side but their action is hurting you or your interest.

Sample Sentence: Edward is pro-gun but he lives in Chicago where gun control is very popular and he might face consequences such as being alienated around his friends if he decides to directly advocate for pro-gun policy. So he tries to indirectly advocate for pro-gun policy by giving an [word] argument which is an extremely flawed anti-gun argument that indirectly points out all the con of gun control while failed to mention all the pros.

Backstabber doesn't feel like the right word.

Comment: Do they think they’re helping or do they know they’re undermining?

Comment: @KillingTime Good to know. This is my first post and I will edit the question.

Comment: @Jim Yes, they know that they are undermining you and your interest but do not want to do it implicitly to avoid possible problems.

Comment: Metaphorically speaking, I'd say such a person is a [***fifth columnist***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_column)

Comment: Maybe the phrase [**Trojan horse**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+Trojan+horse) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

This is called **Straw man**

> an argument, claim, or opponent that is invented in order to win or create an argument:

*The idea that national identity will be lost as a result of European integration is just a straw man which he is wasting his time fighting.*

[Cambridge]

Comment: I don't know if that is the word I'm going for. I think strawman focuses too much on the action itself and not enough on the psychology of the person doing the action.